# AlertDialog leaks despite using a WeakReference

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, weak-references

I have a problem with creating AlertDialog inside a Handler, because it causes memory leaks or another errors.

#### Details:

I have an Activity, Thread and Handler with a WeakReference to an activity. 
Before I start my thread, I create ProgressDialog `dialog` in my activity class.
Thread task have a reference to MyHandler object.
When user dismisses `dialog` in my activity, the onCancelListener calls thread's interrupt(). My thread finishes safely task and send Message DOWNLOAD_STATE.CANCELLED to main activity thread. Then I cretate AlertDialog with code inside `MyHandler`

#### Problem:

The problem is when the user press a back button immediately after dismissing `alert` (which cancells thread) and before new `AlertDialog` has been created (inside MyHandler class). It tooks about second. When user doesn't press back in this time, everything is working.

It leaks here (inside MyHandler class):
 `new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage("update cancelled").setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();`

The normal thing is when user presses the back button, activity is destroyed (effect of activity onBackKeyPressed), but why handleMessage isn't stopped and creates `AlertDialog`?

**My handler class:**

```
static class MyHandler extends Handler {

    WeakReference<MainActivity> activityRef;
    MyHandler(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.activityRef=new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        MainActivity activity=activityRef.get();
        if(activity==null)
            return;

        if (msg.arg1==DownloadTask.DOWNLOAD_STATE.FINISHED.ordinal())
        {
            activity.dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if( msg.arg1== DownloadTask.DOWNLOAD_STATE.CANCELLED.ordinal())
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage("update cancelled").setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
        }

        else if(msg.arg1==DownloadTask.DOWNLOAD_STATE.ERROR.ordinal())
        {

              activity.dialog.dismiss();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.no_connection_info)).setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
        }

    }
}
```

**Inside thread's runnable:**

```
if(Thread.interrupted()) 
        {
            Message msg=handler.obtainMessage();
            msg.arg1=DOWNLOAD_STATE.CANCELLED.ordinal();
            msg.arg2=counter;
            msg.obj=cities.length;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);

            return;
        }
```

**Error stack trace1:**

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mycompany.mooz.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42723848 that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:403)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:311)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:902)
        at com.mycompany.mooz.MainActivity$MyHandler.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Error stack trace 2:**

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@427329e0 is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:700)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:902)
        at com.mycompany.mooz.MainActivity`enter code here`$MyHandler.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Activity com.mycompany.mooz.MainActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42723848 that
>   was originally added here

it usually happens when the `Activity` is being paused and the dialog is still at screen. Keep a reference to your Dialog and call dismiss in `onPause` if the reference is not null and the dialog `isShowing`

```
  if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
  }
```

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@427329e0 is not valid; is your activity
>   running?

this usually happens when you try to show a dialog while the Activity is being paused. To avoid check the `isFinishing` flag

```
  if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()) {
      // show dialog
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding `!activity.isFinishing()` solved problems :-)